# Compiled .NET application - get property value at runtime

Tags: .net, runtime, debugging, obfuscation, deobfuscation

I have a piece of software, which is obfuscated. I need to get value of a specific property it assigns to a control. EXE deobfuscation isn't an option. Is there any tool I can use to get the value at runtime? Can it be done in debugger, if yes, then how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've disassembled the executable and modified IL instructions to output the required property, then re-assembled it.

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to get at the information using Spy++, bundled with Visual Studio ( non express ).  Very much depends on the information you are actually looking for.

(Edit for actual instructions)

Load Spy++ ( or 64bit )
Chose Spy->Find Window...
Drag Find Window Icon onto the Window you are looking for.
Find your control.

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm looking for a control-specific property, so Spy++ doesn't help in any way

Answer (score 0):

It won't be easy - the purpose of obfuscation is to stop you doing this.

The easiest approach is to ask the vendor to supply the value to you via a public API. If they say no, then you shouldn't be hacking their software anyway.

Comment: I wasn't looking for an easy way, but for a proper way to make it. Eventually, I've disassembled the executable, and modified IL instructions to output the required property, then re-assembled it.